# asp.net session different values for one key

Tags: asp.net, session, handler

In my generic handler I try to get some value from session. But sometimes for one session I have different values.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    ...
    string someVar = context.Session["some_key"];
    ...
}
```

Session["some_key"] value initialized on web page (once), and then user call handler. And problem is that after several postback requests context.Session["some_key"] gives me different value. Can it be cause of "Max Worker Processes" setting of app pool?

Comment: Do experience this when logged in as same user? Sessions are per clients, which means a Session is only available per client that accesses your website and every user may have their own session

Comment: Which also means that viewing the page in two different browsers means different Sessions for each. Also, you should specify that your handler wants to use the session object (using `IRequiresSessionState` or `IReadOnlySessionState`).

Comment: It's guest session, same browser (sessionId the same i've checked it) . Handler implements IRequiresSessionState.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are not storing any value in the Session. Because of that, ASP.NET is generating a new session with each new request.

Find more help here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx

> If your application requires a static session ID for the entire session, you can either implement the **Session_Start** method in the application's Global.asax file and store data in the Session object to fix the session ID, **or you can use code in another part of your application** to explicitly store data in the Session object.

Adding something like this somewhere in your code should do it:

```
context.Session["dummy"] = 0;
```

What's more, try to run a search before asking questions to avoid *[duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110354/irequiressessionstate-does-not-work)*:

Comment: Actually I said that "Session["some_key"] value initialized on web page", so it's not the problem.